# gianfar storm protection

Tags: networking

On my ls1021 (ARMv7 Processor rev 5) running 4.14 kernel I can see some storm protection parameters for gianfar network driver.

```
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:ethernet@2d90000/net/eth0/stormprot_count    
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:ethernet@2d90000/net/eth0/stormprot_events    
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:ethernet@2d90000/net/eth0/stormprot_current    
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:ethernet@2d90000/net/eth0/stormprot_window    
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:ethernet@2d90000/net/eth0/stormprot_delay
```

How does it work, and how do I activate it?

Answer (score 0):

```
FRAMEREJ_COUNT=60
FRAMEREJ_WINDOW=10
FRAMEREJ_DELAY=500
echo $FRAMEREJ_COUNT > /sys/class/net/eth1/stormprot_count
echo $FRAMEREJ_WINDOW > /sys/class/net/eth1/stormprot_window
echo $FRAMEREJ_DELAY > /sys/class/net/eth1/stormprot_delay
```

Then the kernel writes this in case of a network storm, instead of a reboot

```
2020-07-30T13:39:15.255130+0200 kernel: kern.warn: net_ratelimit: 2540 callbacks suppressed
2020-07-30T13:39:15.255190+0200 kernel: kern.warn: br0: received packet on eth1 with own address as source address (addr:00:26:77:01:ea:7e, vlan:0)
2020-07-30T13:39:15.255199+0200 kernel: kern.warn: br0: received packet on eth1 with own address as source address (addr:00:26:77:01:ea:7e, vlan:0)
```